# Cursor возвращает неправильный id контакта

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, androidx, android-cursor

У меня есть приложение, которое получает список контактов и контактные данные. Все данные отображаются в двух фрагментах. Основной фрагмент содержит список контактов. Когда я нажимаю на какой-либо элемент, он возвращает идентификатор контакта. Если я выбираю первый элемент списка - все правильно, но если выбрать другой контакт, он возвращает неверный идентификатор.

```
 override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        (parent?.adapter as? CursorAdapter)?.cursor?.apply {
            moveToPosition(position)
            val contactId = getLong(CONTACT_ID_INDEX)

            startActivity(Intent(activity, DetailedActivity::class.java).also {
                it.putExtra(SELECTED_CONTACT_INDEX, contactId)
            })
        }
    }
```

Ниже привожу код загрузчика контактов:

```
class ContactLoader(private val context: FragmentActivity?) : LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private var cursorAdapter: SimpleCursorAdapter? = null

    private val fromColumns: Array<String> = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    )

    private val toIds = intArrayOf(
        R.id.contact_name,
        R.id.contact_phone
    )

    private val projection: Array<out String> = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    )

    fun initContactLoader() {

        cursorAdapter = context?.let {
            LoaderManager.getInstance(it).initLoader(0, null, this)

            SimpleCursorAdapter(
                it,
                R.layout.contact_list_item,
                null,
                fromColumns, toIds,
                0
            )
        }
    }

    fun getAdapter() = cursorAdapter

    override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> = context?.let {
        CursorLoader(
            it,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        )
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException()

    override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, data: Cursor?) {
        cursorAdapter?.swapCursor(data)
    }

    override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>) {
        cursorAdapter?.swapCursor(null)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val sortOrder: String =
            "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY} ASC"
    }

}
```

Comment: Что `moveToPosition()` возвращает?

Comment: Все время возвращает true

Comment: Так же в список загружаются только 3 из 4 контаков. Заметил это только сегодня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Решение**: для отображение я использовал id элемента в курсоре, а не сам id контакта. Для получения его нужно было добавить поле ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID в projection. После чего все отображается верно.

P.S. Также я поменял значение константы CONTACT_ID_INDEX с 0 на 1